# Сократить массив регулярным выражением

Tags: javascript

У меня есть код

const Site = ["site.ru/news/", "site.ua/news/", "site.kg/news/"];

А можно как-то сократить эту запись, чтобы не приходилось в массиве перечислять все сайты? По сути там одинаковые элементы массива, отличающиеся только буквами .ru, .by, .ua и т.д.

Можно как-то при помощи регулярных выражений в массив все эти записи добавить?

Comment: регулярные выражения то тут при чем? вам тут разве что какое-нить `const domains = ['ru', 'ua', 'kg'];` и `let news = domains.map(d => \`site.${d}/news\`)` поможет

Comment: регулярные выражения обратную задачу решают, из трех имеющихся ссылок получить 3 возможных домена

Comment: А без перечислений доменов никак не обойтись? Я думал точку и эти две буквы регулярным выражением заменить можно.